# SQL Cross Join better in performance than normal join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm currently working with SQL and wondered about cross join.
Assuming I have the following relations:

```
customer(customerid, firstname, lastname)
transact(customerid, productid, date, quantity)
product(productid, description)
```

This query is written in Oracle SQL. It should select the last name of all customers which bought more than 1000 quantities of a product (rather senseless but no matter):

```
SELECT c.lastname, t.date
FROM customer c, transact t
WHERE t.quantity > 1000
AND t.customerid = c.customerid
```

Isn't this doing a cross join?! Isn't this extremely slow when the tables consist of a huge amount of data?
Isn't it better to do something like this:

```
SELECT c.lastname, t.date
FROM customer c
JOIN transact t ON(c.customerid = t.customerid)
WHERE t.quantity > 1000
```

Which is better in performance? And how are these queries handled internally?

Thanks for your help,
Barbara

Comment: Of course the 1st is a CROSS JOIN, performance will be horrible, but it's a totally different result as the 2nd query

Comment: The first is **not** a cross join. It's a regular inner join - the join condition is simply in the `where` clause - this is how joins where defined in the SQL89 standard.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for your answer, I corrected it. Now the queries should deliver the same result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, this might be the reason why our teacher told us that the first possiblity is prefered when retrieving data of more than one table.

Comment: The implicit, error prone join condition in the `where` clause was replaced with the explicit `JOIN` operator in the SQL92 standard - over 20 years ago. There is no reason to use the old syntax anymore. Using an explicit `JOIN` operator is definitely "preferred" nowadays - you can send your teacher a link to my comment if you want to - he/she should get used to "modern" SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've been learning the "right" SQL in high school for the last few years where we had the latest material from Oracle...now at university we are taught this :( just another sign to never believe everything you are told, not even from your teachers!

Comment: You could ask your teacher if she/he can spot the error in this statement: http://txt.do/fpgz  in less then 10 seconds (hint: if you rewrite it to use an `explicit` join you'll get a syntax error)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Before the edit there was no `AND t.customerid = c.customerid` :-)

Comment: I'm in complete agreement with @a_horse_with_no_name's comment regarding ANSI joins. Use of implicit joins in new development is a  code review fail where I work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries aren't equivalent, because:

```
SELECT lastname, date
FROM customer, transact
WHERE quantity > 1000
```

Doesn't actually limit to customers that bought > 1000, it's simply taking every combination of rows from those two tables, and excluding any with quantity less than or equal to 1000 (all customers will be returned).

This query is equivalent to your `JOIN` version:

```
SELECT lastname, date
FROM customer c, transact t
WHERE quantity > 1000
  AND c.customerid = t.customerid
```

The explicit `JOIN` version is preferred as it's not deprecated syntax, but both should have the same execution plan and identical performance.  The explicit `JOIN` version is easier to read in my opinion, but the fact that the comma listed/implicit method has been outdated for over a decade (two?) should be enough reason to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, recognized this and corrected it. Thank you for your answer. 
I was wondering about this topic because our professor at university tells us hour for hour that cross joins are much better in performance than simple inner joins - and I couldn't believe that. Are there any languages where cross joins are more performant?

Comment: However, I also prefer the one with the explicit JOIN statement.

Comment: @Babs Any modern database query optimizer should handle them identically.  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle for sure, pretty confident that PostgreSQL and SQLite would too.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If you want to know how they are handled then look at the query plan.

In your case, the queries are *not* the same.  The first does a `cross join` with conditions on only one table.  The second does a legitimate `join`.  The second is the right way to write the query.

However, even if you included the correct `where` clause in the first query, then the performance should be the same.  Oracle is smart enough to recognize that the two queries do the same thing (if written correctly).

Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Oh I forgot to write the condition that customerids are the same...correcting it.

Comment: The first isn't a cross join. It's regular inner join with the join condition in the `where` clause. This is how joins where defined in the initial SQL89 (or was it SQL 86?) standard.

Comment: Yup, the corrected version [of the 2nd code block] will have the same plan as the FROM clause [3rd code block].